# D R M based computing in Blender

Tags: drmaa

Can 2.79 blender or 2.80 blender (Linux Versions) take advantabe of multiple GPU cards?  If so, how many in same motherboard.

I have hundreds of GPU cards and motherboards available.  Looking for correct drivers for RX 580 series RADION GPUs for LINUX that will work with blender.

Comment: Have you tried the official drivers by AMD? https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-580

Comment: Yes,  that was my first step.  When I rebooted, the  devices became visible in /dev/ folder and inside /dev/drm/ with different names.